# delete a certain numbers of char from the end

Tags: c

in one of my exercise I ask the user to insert an address of file in is computer like this C:\Users\Rony\Desktop\file.txt to do some changes. I save this address in a string. So in order to do changes I will like to change this string to tmp.txt for example, so the address will be now C:\Users\Rony\Desktop\tmp.txt. In fact because the address is not the same between computers i would like to delete from the end to the first \ all the characters and add to this tmp.txt. But i don't know why my code doesn't work
Thanks you

```
for (i = strlen(adress1); i > 0; i--)
{
if (adress1[i] == "\\")
  {
    adress[i] = 0;
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Show some of your effort.

Comment: I don't have any idea how to do this, so I ask you in order to help me

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: A few general tips though: To shorten a string, all you have to do is to change one character to the string terminator character `'\0'`. There are also functions to [*concatenate* strings](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat).

Comment: i know but who can I get the last / of my string. can you show me an example

Comment: There are [many string functions in the standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte), look through them and I'm sure you can find some that will help you.

Comment: the last of your string is `strlen(yourstring)-1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewriting your filename might cause a problem if the name of the file is smaller than the new name. I.e. the user selected `C:\a.txt` and you want to rename it to `C:\tmp.txt`. This would cause an error since the array bound would be exceeded. Hence you have to create a new array. The code below works, but is not really nice to look at. Since you are not familiar with the string functions, I thought this might be the best way to go. But I highly recommend to look at these provided functions in order to reduce the amount of written code and increase the readability.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char* p = "C:\\a.txt";
    int x; // this will hold the position of the last backslash
    int i;
    for(i = 0; p[i] != '\0'; i++){
        if(p[i] == '\\') {
            x = i;
        }
    }
    char pp[x+9];
    pp[x+8] = '\0';
    for(i = 0; i <= x; i++){
        pp[i] = p[i]; 
    }
    pp[i+0] = 't';
    pp[i+1] = 'm';
    pp[i+2] = 'p';
    pp[i+3] = '.';
    pp[i+4] = 't';
    pp[i+5] = 'x';
    pp[i+6] = 't';

    printf("%s -> %s\n", p, pp);
    return (0);
}
```

**Edit**

Instead of doing every operation by hand, one can use the built-in [library functions](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ansi_c/c_function_references.htm). Using these will make the code much shorter and easier to understand.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char* p = "C:\\a.txt"; // the path
    char* t = "tmp.txt"; // the new name of the file
    char* e = strchr(p, '\\'); // returns a pointer to the last occurence of the backslash within the string p
    int i = (int)(e-p); // i contains the index position of the last occurence of the backslash
    char n[i+1+strlen(t)]; // create a string with max size i + 1 + length of t
    strncpy(n, p, i+1);// copy the first (i+1) characters of p to n 
    strncpy(&n[i+1], t, strlen(t)+1); // copy the whole string t and \0 to the end of the new path   
    printf("%s -> %s\n", p, n);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: OP may be unfamiliar to the basic `string.h` functions, but that is no reason to not use **any** of them at all. In fact, introducing the correct ones to him may be much mote helpful.

Comment: @RadLexus thanks for your feedback. I added a functionally equivalent code using the built-in functions.

Answer (score 1):

To "delete" part of a C string, all you need to do is set the character after the last one you want to keep to a `0`. (I say "delete" (quoted) here because you don't actually remove anything from memory; the 'string' gets shorter but the amount of memory allocated for it stays the same, and all content beyond the `0` is still available.)

There is a standard `string.h` function to locate the last occurrence of a certain character: [`strrchr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strrchr). This returns a

> [p]ointer to the found character in `str`, or null pointer if no such character is found

So to locate the last backslash and to lop off what's behind it, you can use

```
char *ptr;
ptr = strrchr (address1, '\\');
if (ptr) ptr[1] = 0;
```

Note the explicit test to see if `ptr` actually found a backslash.

Now you don't actually *want* to discard everything after that backslash, you want to copy something new in it. For that, you don't need to first make it shorter and then (presumably) use `strcat`, you can use `strcpy` right away:

```
ptr = strrchr (address1, '\\');
if (ptr)
    strcpy (ptr+1, "tmp.txt");
else
    strcpy (address1, "tmp.txt");
```

which, personally, I usually write as

```
ptr = strrchr (address1, '\\');
if (ptr) ptr++; else ptr = address1;
strcpy (ptr, "tmp.txt");
```

Note that both use `ptr+1` because `ptr` itself points "at" the backslash; and you want to keep it.

There is an inherent danger in using string concatenations such as this: if the part after the last backslash is shorter than the newly inserted string, you can overwrite data after the string. This depends *entirely* on how you created `address1` in the first place. A **very dirty fix** is to explicitly test if the *current* contents of `address1` has enough space left:

```
char *to_add = "tmp.txt";
ptr = strrchr (address1, '\\');
if (ptr && strlen(ptr+1) <= strlen(to_add) )
    strcpy (ptr+1, to_add);
else
    printf ("too long, ignored\n");
```

(I only add this for completeness; you probably should not use this in production code.)

The reason `strcpy` (and `strcat`, and related string functions) cannot know if there is 'enough' space left is because a simple C string does not store the available maximum length anywhere.